# Program using switch to calculate Simple and compound interest

Tags: c, turbo-c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
void main()
{
    float p,r,t,si,ci,a,temp;
    int ch;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter p,r,t");
    scanf("%f%f%f",&p,&r,&t);
    printf("\n 1 for SI");
    printf("\n 2 for CI");
    printf("\n Select any option");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1:
            si=(p*r*t)/100;
            printf("The simple interest is %f",si);
            break;
        case 2:
            temp=(1+r/100);
            a=p*pow(temp,t);
            ci=a-p;
            printf("The compound interest is %f",ci);
            break;
    }
    getch();
}
```

This is the code I have written and there are no errors. I can properly input the p,r and t. When I enter 1 or 2 (the choice for SI and CI), the output screen closes automatically and there is no output shown. I can only see the code which I had written. Please tell me what my mistake is.

Comment: TurboC, bad indentation, `void main()`...eww

Comment: Try ending the `printf`s with `\n`, not starting them. If that did not work, mention your inputs for the `scanf`s

Comment: I am just a beginner and have been taught this way. Help me improve please.

Comment: 2,3,4 were the inputs I gave

Comment: @GauravLakhotia http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You were taught to write badly-formatted code?  If it's not easy to read, we may as well move on to the next question that is.

Comment: @GauravLakhotia I put some indentation on your code to make it easier to read

Comment: try putting more getch() and check...

Comment: Also use `int main (void)` for your main function, and `return 0;` for success or others for failure at the end

Comment: @VikasJoshi `getch` reads from the keyboard, not the `stdin`. So, I don't it'll work as the  trailing `\n` isn't the problem.

Comment: @CoolGuy IIRC `getch()` consumes from stdin, no?

Comment: @Magisch Nope. Keyboard, not `stdin`.

Comment: @CoolGuy must be thinking about getchar then

Comment: Have you attempted to print the data that you think you entered so you can be sure the computer/program received what you thought it got?  Using `\n` at the end of the `printf()` statements may make the difference; it is good practice, regardless. Have you checked the return values from `scanf()`?  The first should return 3, the second 1; if they don't, you've got problems.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use

```
int main()
```

and the return int at the end.

Then did you take a look at your var values ? 
Using float without separation what can you enter ? "2.34.678.9"? how to differenciate the values ? prefer to use %f %f %f in your scanf. Retry after :)

Comment: The `2.34.678.9` is unambiguously 2.34, 0.678, 0.9, though it would be silly to enter it like that).  It wouldn't make any odds whether there were spaces between the `%f` conversion specifications — `%f` skips spaces anyway.